# php, get src from iframe preg_replace

Tags: php, iframe

I have a string that contains iframe

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.test.com/" title="test" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

how do i use preg_replace to extract the link that contains it; I have to extract the following link
'https://www.test.com/'

obvious by clearing the string from the iframe tag

// I HAVE SOLVED THIS

```
 $stringaiframe = 'test inserisco ifram tag <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.test.com/" title="test" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$stringaiframe = preg_replace('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=("[^"]+").*?<\/iframe>/', '""""""$1""""""', $stringaiframe);
```

Comment: can you assign id to this iframe? or its populating from some other source

Comment: @sohailamar It's not a dom element. OP says it's a _string_

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything not working with `DomDocument`?

Comment: Also, is this string fixed? Which parts can change, which cannot?

Comment: ok i solved, use $stringa = 'test inserisco ifram tag <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.test.com/" title="test" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$res = preg_replace('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/iframe>/', '$1', $stringa);

Answer (score 1):

I'd go about it with `stripos`. Find the first occurrence of string 'src="', and from there find the firs ocurrence of '"'. What's in between is your URL.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply split this string.

```
var str = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.test.com/" title="test" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var src = str.split('src=')[1].split(/[ >]/)[0];
alert("source ===>" + src)
```

**Update**
If you want this in php use this script.

```
$str = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.test.com/" title="test" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $str, $match);
$url = $match[1];
```

This script will give you the src of iframe. please check and let me know

Comment: I need it in php

Comment: you didn't mentioned it

Comment: is inserted in the title

Comment: @natoduevolte
I have updated the php script too

Comment: it should just extract src of the iframe, in this case, your code extracts src from any tag, i only care about iframe tag, if i have img tag, i don't want to extract anything